# MacBook Pro USB ports not working properly

Tags: macbook-pro, ios, ipad, usb, charging

At work, I usually use my left USB port to charge my iPhone, while the right port connects to a hub on my monitor, providing Ethernet, external keyboard and sometimes another iOS device. I also have the monitor itself connected via one of the Thunderbolt ports. The computer is connected to the mains.

All of this works fine, but recently I've had some what I believe to be power-related issues with the ports. If I try to plug my iPad mini 2 into either port, it doesn't charge correctly (it keeps chiming to say it's charging, randomly, every second or so).

Another symptom appears to be that if I try to run Duet (the iOS/OS X app combo that allows you to run your iOS device as an external screen), it keeps trying to connect, the screens flash black, then come back, then keep coming and going but never connects properly to the iOS device. This is even the case if I'm using my iPhone, which doesn't usually have any problems charging.

I've tried removing all external devices and just plugging in the iPhone, and Duet still doesn't work properly. Same with the iPad and charging, if no other devices are connected, it still beeps all the time and doesn't charge properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually (depending on MBP model) - there is only one fully powered / full speed bus.

You could try resetting the PRAM / NVRAM which also causes a restart to be sure it’s not a temporary situation.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Here is a good support article on USB ports and their corresponding power.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204377

From my experience iPads can request a lot of power from a standard USB port. Since power management could be involved, the SMC - System Management Controller decides when to apply or deny charging current. You might want to try one time resetting that for your Mac.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

If you still have USB issues once that’s done - see about hardware service either in or out of the standard warranty process.

Comment: Just got into similar situation. Just start from giving a try to another cable. I have a cable which charges devices perfectly from network charger, but acts exactly as described when trying to charge from macbook.