# Only one USB-C port will charge my MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt, charging, charger

I've had my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) for over a year and I've never had any problems with charging until now. I was always able to use both USB-C ports for charging, but I just tried using the port that I don't usually use for charging (the one closest to me) and it just doesn't charge. I can use this same port to charge my phone, but when I try to charge my MacBook with it, it just does nothing. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is wrong with the standard mag safe connector for charging?

Comment: I have the 2016 MacBook Pro, it does not have any MagSafe ports. It only has 2 USB-C ports, which it uses for charging. They should both work for charging, but at the moment, only one does.

Comment: I have the same problem on slightly different hardware. MacBook Pro 15inch model 13.3
Will only charge in one USB port on left side, confusingly the other port has stopped working previously, but function returned. Apart from not charging, the port works for other purposes.

Comment: @MartinTjersland Do either the answers here help you?

Answer (score 12):

So, to summarize, the port works for all functions (USB connectivity, display, etc) including charging downstream devices (like a smartphone), but you cannot charge the MacBook.

- Your SMC chip needs to be reset.  Hold <kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> <kbd>⦿ Power</kbd> from a powered off state.
- There is failed component in the charging circuitry.

USB 3.1 (power delivery) negotiates power.  When you connect your power adapter to the port, it basically says "I'm a power adapter and I can charge."  The device (MacBook) will respond "I need X" and will negotiate with adapter for what can be delivered.  Once negotiated, the adapter sends the power and the USB port passes it to the charging circuit (handled by the SMC)

What could be happening here is one of two things:

- The port is no longer negotiating for power (unlikely because the port still functions otherwise
- The charging circuitry physically isn't getting the power (a broken electrical path)

If the SMC reset doesn't fix, take it in for service.

Answer (score 6):

The SMC - System Management Controller decides when to apply charge, so you might want to try one time resetting that for your Mac.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

If you still have charging issues once that’s done - see about hardware service either in or out of the standard warranty process.

General USB / Thunderbolt troubleshooting has some other things to try so you can read up on that here:

- [MacBook Pro USB ports not working properly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223626/macbook-pro-usb-ports-not-working-properly)